# Keydown allowing numbers but not shift symbols on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html

I have an event bound to an input that should only allow numbers.  Simplified:

```
function (e) {
    if (-1 === [48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57].indexOf(e.keyCode)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

This works fine, but if someone types <kbd>!</kbd>, <kbd>@</kbd>, <kbd>#</kbd>, <kbd>$</kbd>, etc. the keyCode is still the same and the event default is not prevented.

On a physical keyboard, I can prevent this pretty simply by also checking `e.shiftKey`.  However, on an iOS *virtual* keyboard, some of those characters exist (such as `$`) even for `<input type=number>` and they can be typed directly.  Their keyCode is the same, but it seems like `e.shiftKey` is still falsey.

There are a variety of possible solutions that would be acceptable to me:

- Have the virtual keyboard itself *not* display these characters (i.e. only display numbers and a period/decimal)
- Detect that an invalid virtual key was pressed and suppress the event behavior
- Determine the an invalid character will be added to the input's value and suppress the event behavior in this case
- Others?

Comment: Check if last character is bad and delete. No need for preventDefault.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<input type="tel" />` to limit the input to numbers in iOS -- although this also allows '*' and '#' to be typed, at least it's less work since you'd only have to check for those two characters