# Prevent typing non-numeric in input type number

Tags: javascript, html

Using `<input type=number>` will cause `this.value` inside of an event listener to return an empty string if the input is not a valid number.  You can see an example of this at http://jsfiddle.net/fSy53/

However, the invalid characters are still displayed in the input.

Is there any way to get the value that is actually *displayed*, including the invalid characters, from within an event listener?

My ultimate goal is to prevent users from actually typing any non-numeric characters into the field.  I need to use `type=number` so that the numeric virtual keyboard is used by mobile devices.  My goal would be to do something like `this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "")` on `keyup keypress`, but this doesn't work because if an invalid character is typed, reading from `this.value` returns `""`.

Comment: I think this was asked before and the answer was no, let me dig it up.  **EDIT: here is is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090810/getting-the-value-of-a-html5-number-input**

Comment: About the numeric keyboard: There is a new HTML5 attribute `inputmode` that could be set to `numeric` to show a numeric keyboard. Unfortunately no browser supports it yet, according to [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

Comment: Note that the issue described happens in Firefox, but not in Chrome. Chrome will prevent non-numeric characters from appearing in an input if `type='number'` is set.

Comment: Update regarding the `inputmode` attribute: it is still not supported in any browser by default (see http://caniuse.com/#search=inputmode), but can optionally be enabled in Firefox by setting the `dom.forms.inputmode` flag.

Comment: hmmm... isnt "e" the only "invalid" character thats displayed in an `type=number`??

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62070692/1692889

Comment: Preventing users from entering a non-numeric character (i.e. BREAKING their keyboard) is not very user friendly. A user friendly approach is to allow them to type and explain what is wrong. A user that is trying to enter a string into a number input will not understand why his keyboard stopped working. I'm surprised how many developers strive to implement this anti user feature. This goes to all blocking behaviors (max-length, patterns), very non user friendly. Not to mention that users do not usually look at their screen while typing.

Comment: @Cesar, I agree. But what about submit-blocking specifically? The `pattern` is not an input-blocking behavior; a `pattern` only blocks in upon submit (in Chrome at least). And some input-blocking is browser-controlled; the `min/max` and `min/max-length` fields do block input, a possible accessibility problem that is on the browser to fix.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Try preventing the default behaviour if you don't like the incoming key value:

```
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keypress", function (evt) {
    if (evt.which < 48 || evt.which > 57)
    {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: `keypress` event is only fired on the document. You'd need to setup a keyboard manager for this

Comment: Not true.  keypress fires on the input element, and bubbles to document

Comment: @megawac do you have a citation for that?  That's contrary to my experience.  The OP stated that preventing non-numeric contents is the goal, I think this is the right approach: prevent it before it happeans and don't worry about the .value

Comment: @GlennLane the problem is that for shift keys such as `$` the `.which` is the same as for the non-shift key and on the virtual keyboards, `e.shiftKey` is not set to a truthy value.  Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964074/keydown-allowing-numbers-but-not-shift-symbols-on-iphone

Comment: I don't find that behaviour on my browser... $ -> 36, 4 -> 52.  Must be a Chrome thing.

Comment: @GlennLane by virtual keyboards I mean on like an iPhone or something.  Even if it were a Chrome thing, that's no good.  I need to support more browsers than just the one your solution works for

Comment: The issue was using `keyup` -- it records the same key code (or `which` or whatever it is) based on the key typed.  Keypress does seem to work consistently.

Comment: be aware that this blocks "tab" as well in firefox, but not in chrome

Comment: With this you can't press arrow, backspace etc keys, there is extended solution exists http://stackoverflow.com/a/995193/691194

Comment: if (isNaN(parseInt(evt.key,10)))
      {
          evt.preventDefault();
      }

Comment: Unable to backspace with your solution, @EugenSunic

Comment: oninput ------- better to use

Answer (score 26):

You can accomplish this by preventing the keyPress event from occurring for non-numeric values

e.g (using jQuery)

```
$('.input-selector').on('keypress', function(e){
  return e.metaKey || // cmd/ctrl
    e.which <= 0 || // arrow keys
    e.which == 8 || // delete key
    /[0-9]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which)); // numbers
})
```

This accounts for all different types of input (e.g. input from the number pad has different codes than the keyboard) as well as backspace, arrow keys, control/cmd + r to reload etc

Comment: The arrow key codes are 37 through 40 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863329/are-up-down-left-right-arrow-keycodes-always-the-same

Comment: **e.which == 46** for dot key if float are needed

Comment: Note that there are  other ways to insert into an html input, like copy past, drop and autofill so on...

Answer (score 19):

Please note that **e.which**, **e.keyCode** and **e.charCode** are deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which

I prefer **e.key**:

```
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
    var allowedChars = '0123456789.';
    function contains(stringValue, charValue) {
        return stringValue.indexOf(charValue) > -1;
    }
    var invalidKey = e.key.length === 1 && !contains(allowedChars, e.key)
            || e.key === '.' && contains(e.target.value, '.');
    invalidKey && e.preventDefault();});
```

This function doesn't interfere with control codes in Firefox (<kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, etc) by checking the string length: `e.key.length === 1`.

It also prevents duplicate dots at the beginning and between the digits: `e.key === '.' && contains(e.target.value, '.')`

Unfortunately, it doesn't prevent multiple dots at the end: `234....`

It seems there is no way to cope with it.

Comment: I like this approach. It is clean and works well. One issue with it is that it blocks things like `Ctrl+R` (reload current page), `Ctrl+A`, etc. I believe it is safe to add an `!e.ctrlKey` check.

Comment: The keypress event is also deprecated. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event and also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event

Answer (score 8):

The other answers seemed more complicated than necessary so I adapted their answers to this short and sweet function.

```
function allowOnlyNumbers(event) {
  if (event.key.length === 1 && /\D/.test(event.key)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

It won't do change the behavior of any arrow, enter, shift, ctrl or tab keys because the length of the key property for those events is longer than a single character.  It also uses a simple regular expressions to look for any non digit character.

Comment: so what about if somebody wants decimal numbers? such as `10.01`? And that doesn't prevent `1.1.1` from submission.

Comment: pressing CTRL + X won't work with this

Comment: @D-rk Add `!e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.metaKey &&` to the `if` condition.

Answer (score 4):

This solution seems to be working well for me. It builds on @pavok's solution by preserving ctrl key commands.

```
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
  if (
    e.key.length === 1 && e.key !== '.' && isNaN(e.key) && !e.ctrlKey || 
    e.key === '.' && e.target.value.toString().indexOf('.') > -1
  ) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: best solution so far

Answer (score 3):

```
inputs[5].addEventListener('keydown', enterNumbers);

function enterNumbers(event) {
  if ((event.code == 'ArrowLeft') || (event.code == 'ArrowRight') ||
     (event.code == 'ArrowUp') || (event.code == 'ArrowDown') || 
     (event.code == 'Delete') || (event.code == 'Backspace')) {
     return;
  } else if (event.key.search(/\d/) == -1) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

in this case, the value of the input field stays intact when a non-number button is pressed, and still delete, backspace, arrowup-down-left-right work properly and can be used for modifying the digital input.

Answer (score 2):

try this one :

1. current key pressed ->  `e`
2. if `e` is not a number -> `isNaN(e.key)`
3. when condition is true , so default action should not be taken as it normally would be -> `e.preventDefault()`
4. else, return default action... `e`

```js
input.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) {
  if (isNaN(e.key)) e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain what your code does and how it solves the OP's Issue?

Comment: any key pressed is equal to (e) parameter , then if e.key is not a number , return preventDefault() , so what is preventDefault() method ?  ....tells the user agent that if the event does not get explicitly handled, its default action should not be taken as it normally would be.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but I actually was hoping you would edit your answer with those details to improve the quality of your post.  You will notice that when a user answers a question with 'try this' and a few lines of code, the answers rarely perform well

Comment: you right , sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I will add MetaKey as well, as I am using MacOS

```
input.addEventListener("keypress", (e) => {
    const key = e.key;
    if (!(e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey) && key.length === 1 && !/\d\./.test(key)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Or, you can try `!isNaN(parseFloat(key))`

Answer (score 1):

**Update on the accepted answer:**

Because of many properties becoming deprecated

> (property) KeyboardEvent.which: number @deprecated

you should just rely on the **key** property and create the rest of the logic by yourself:

The code allows Enter, Backspace and all numbers [0-9], every other character is disallowed.

```
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keypress", ({ key, preventDefault }) => {
  if (isNaN(parseInt(key, 10)) && !['Backspace', 'Enter'].includes(key)) {
      preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**NOTE**
This will disable paste action

Answer (score 0):

Based on Nrzonline's answer: I fixed the problem of the multiple "." at the end of the input by adding a

```
let lastCharacterEntered
```

outside of the input and then onKeyPress

```
e => {
          var allowedChars = "0123456789.";
          function contains(stringValue, charValue) {
            return stringValue.indexOf(charValue) > -1;
          }
          var invalidKey =
            (e.key.length === 1 && !contains(allowedChars, e.key)) ||
            (e.key === "." && contains(e.target.value, "."));
          console.log(e.target.value);
          invalidKey && e.preventDefault();
          if (!invalidKey) {
            if (lastCharacterEntered === "." && e.key === ".") {
              e.preventDefault();
            } else {
              lastCharacterEntered = e.key;
            }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and discovered an alternative solution using the validation API - works without black magic in all major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) except IE. This solution simply prevents users from entering invalid values.
I also included a fallback for IE, which is not nice but works at least.

Context: **onInput** function is called on input events, **setInputValue** is used to set the value of the input element, **previousInputValue** contains the last valid input value (updated in setInputValue calls).

```
    function onInput (event) {
        const inputValue = event.target.value;

        // badInput supported on validation api (except IE)
        // in IE it will be undefined, so we need strict value check
        const badInput = event.target.validity.badInput;

        // simply prevent modifying the value
        if (badInput === true) {
        // it's still possible to enter invalid values in an empty input, so we'll need this trick to prevent that
            if (previousInputValue === '') {
                setInputValue(' ');
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setInputValue('');
                }, 1);
            }
            return;
        }

        if (badInput === false) {
            setInputValue(inputValue);
            return;
        }

        // fallback case for IE and other abominations

        // remove everything from the string expect numbers, point and comma
        // replace comma with points (parseFloat works only with points)
        let stringVal = String(inputValue)
            .replace(/([^0-9.,])/g, '')
            .replace(/,/g, '.');

        // remove all but first point
        const pointIndex = stringVal.indexOf('.');
        if (pointIndex !== -1) {
            const pointAndBefore = stringVal.substring(0, pointIndex + 1);
            const afterPoint = stringVal.substring(pointIndex + 1);

            // removing all points after the first
            stringVal = `${pointAndBefore}${afterPoint.replace(/\./g, '')}`;
        }

        const float = parseFloat(stringVal);
        if (isNaN(float)) {
            // fallback to emptying the input if anything goes south
            setInputValue('');
            return;
        }
        setInputValue(stringVal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prevent typing non-Alphabet in specific input id for pages that have more than one input item.it's usable for Oracle Apex developers
--- Append in HTML header of page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateNumber(event) {
  const activeElmnt = document.activeElement;  
  var keyCode = event.keyCode;
  var excludedKeys = [8, 37, 39, 46];
 
   if ( activeElmnt.id == "input id in HTML page"){
        if (!((keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) ||
            (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122) ||
            (excludedKeys.includes(keyCode)))) {
            console.log("alphabets are not allowed");
            event.preventDefault();

  }
}
  console.log("keycode: " + keyCode + "ActiveElemet: "+activeElmnt.id);
}
</script>
```

-- Append in page HTML Body attribute
onkeydown="validateNumber(event);"

Answer (score 0):

here is my simple solution simply
in this solution u should keep the input type to text so when you use `event.target.value` you get the full string not only the numbers or an empty string instead so you actually can check if there is a point yet or not.
and i didn't use the deprecated properties `event.which`

```
isNumber(event) {
      var allowed = "";
      if (event.target.value.includes(".")) {
        allowed = "123456789";
      } else {
        allowed = "123456789.";
      }
      if (!allowed.includes(event.key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }

document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('keypress', isNumber);

the HTML
```

```

```js
 function isNumber(event) {
      var allowed = "";
      if (event.target.value.includes(".")) {
        allowed = "0123456789";
      } else {
        allowed = "0123456789.";
      }
      if (!allowed.includes(event.key)) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
      }
      
      document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('keypress',isNumber);
```

```html
<h3>You can input only numbers and one point (this would be a float or int) </h3>
<input type="text" id="number" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should work. Only works with **integers**.

```
function validateNumberInput(e) {
    if (isNaN(e.key)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

You can however implement floats with few more lines:

```
function validateNumberInput(e) {
    if (isNaN(e.key) && e.key !== '.') {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if (e.key === '.') {
        if (e.target.value.indexOf('.') >= 0) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Finally use it like:

```
targetInput.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    validateNumberInput(e);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try it:

```
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keyup", function () {
   this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/, "")
});
```

Comment: In the event the input contains characters the value is cleared and not just the non-digit characters. This is because the value of a numeric box is a floating point number. Therefore (according to the spec) a non-floating point will set the value of the control to ''.