# prevent displaying of non numeric characters for input type number in mozilla

Tags: html, firefox

In chrome, when we use `<input type='number'`>, if we type any non numeric characters, they are not displayed.

In mozilla, they are displayed. However, when I get `e.target.value`, I am getting an empty string with a validation message `Please enter an number`.

I want the chrome functionality in mozilla - I am  trying to strip out the last character if it is not numeric - but as the value is empty string as soon as non numeric character is entered I am unable to do so.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/19966417/814160

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keypress", function (evt) {
    if(evt.which == 8){return} // to allow BackSpace
    if (evt.which < 48 || evt.which > 57)
    {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
Number: <input type='number'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/zpg8k/1660/

```
$('input[type="number"]').keypress(function(e) {
    var a = [];
    var k = e.which;

    for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
        a.push(i);

    if (!(a.indexOf(k)>=0))
        e.preventDefault();
});
```