# Prevent user from typing non-number input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to allow user to type in numbers only. Here is what I did.

Portion of my directive template:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="5" ng-keypress="allowNumbers($event)">
```

Function in my directive:

```
$scope.allowNumbers= function (ev) {
    var key = ev.charCode || ev.keyCode || 0;
    var allowed = (
        key == 8 ||
        key == 9 ||
        key == 13 ||
        key == 46 ||
        key == 110 ||
        key == 190 ||
        (key >= 35 && key <= 40) ||
        (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
        (key >= 96 && key <= 105));

    return allowed;
};
```

While debugging, I noticed that even the function returns `true` or `false`, the value in textbox does get entered. Can I somehow prevent it for non-number key press?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent typing non-numeric in input type number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966417/prevent-typing-non-numeric-in-input-type-number)

Comment: Is your function named `allowNumbers` or `allowNumberOnly`?

Comment: try to use `if (!allowed) ev.preventDefault();`

Comment: cant you just use type="number"?

Comment: Yeah @LDJ is right if you want only numbers why cant you use number input field rather than text input field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd approach this simpler and in a way that is guaranteed to catch more possible forms of input (e.g. copy-paste):

```
<input type="number" ng-model="myNumber">

$scope.$watch('myNumber', function (input) {
    $scope.myNumber = input.replace(/\D/g, '');
});
```

Comment: If the user copy and paste the data like 'asdd1as3asd3', the outcome as per the described logic will be 133. I don't think that is the intention of the query asked.

Comment: Why not? What *should* it do in that case? The input is only allowed to consist of numbers, stripping out all non-numbers seems entirely reasonable to me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `directive`:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('numbersOnly', function(){
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                if (!inputValue) return ''
                var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                if (transformedInput !== inputValue) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                }

                return transformedInput;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And use it like this:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="5" numbers-only/>
```

You could use this behavior into any input needed just by adding the `numbers-only` attribute.

See [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DwKZh/2498/).

Comment: Your solution is good, except for one thing. If the cursor is in the middle of the number, then type the letter (not numbers), the cursor moves to the end of the **input**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
    function IsNumeric(e) {

var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode));
//  document.getElementById("error").style.display = ret ? "none" : "inline";
return ret;
}
```

and In html

```
     <input type="text"  onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer