# prevent from inputing letters only money format jquery regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```js
$(document).on("input", ".money", function(e) {
  console.log(moneyonly($(this).val()))
  if (moneyonly($(this).val())) {
    return true;

  }
  return false;
});


function moneyonly(amount) {
  var boo = false;

  if ((/^\d*(?:\.\d{2})?$/g).test(amount)) {
    boo = true;
  }
  return boo;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="money" id="">
```

Regex is ok. Even if false it is still typing in the input. How to not allow?

How to allow only the format that is assigned in regex?
Any idea is appreciated

Comment: Just preventDefault on keypress http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966417/prevent-typing-non-numeric-in-input-type-number

Comment: @mplungjan how about copy paste?will it still check it?

Comment: You are right - it won't . But on input can handle that by emptying the field

Answer (score 0):

That is widely supported across browsers

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="5" step=0.001 />
```

Comment: @mplungjan actually one can define a `step` so floats are also possible