# Javascript - Value.replace includes 1 letter

Tags: javascript, forms

I am creating a login page, and i want the username to only have an input of numbers, so it will accept 1000 but if i input 1000t and try to submit the form it should decline it.

I tried doing it a different approach and not allow the user to enter letters at all but when i use my code, it lets me type upto 1 character for some reason. I.e. i can type 1000t but not 1000ttt. If i try to type 1000t followed by a "f" it will replace the t with a f, so ill get 1000f. But i only want numbers to appear

My script:

```
<script>
function validate(evt){
 evt.value = evt.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"");
    }
</script>
```

My form:

```
<form action="customer_login.jsp" method="POST">
  Customer Number: <input type="text" name="username" onkeypress="validate(username)" />
  <br />
  Password: <input type="text" name="password" />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Edit: I also noticed if i type 1001a and press tab, it removes the a, but if i click onto the password box it keeps the a

Comment: You can use `<input type="number">`.

Comment: Almost, but how would i not allow it to use negative numbers then?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 That allows all floating point numbers. From OP's script, it seems like sign and decimal point should be excluded.

Comment: @TedHopp correct, they have to be whole numbers, and the problem is that my actual JSP form only allows input of text, so that's why i wanted to keep type as text i.e. the way i did the login in jsp is a string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966417/prevent-typing-non-numeric-in-input-type-number

Comment: what you are doing here is replacing every character that is not a number [0-9] with `"  "`. Maybe you shoudl try `evt.value = evt.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"");`

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake in my pasting the code onto stack overflow, i dont originally have a space there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `<input type="number">`. This would however include negative numbers, floating point numbers and special numbers (`10e4`, etc.).

If you want to have a regular expression, you can pass the element to the JavaScript function by using `this`. Then, replace the value of the element by the modified, new value. Your problem occurred, because you used `onkeypress`. This event is immediately fired when you press a key. The actual letter is added only after releasing the key. So, you need to use `onkeyup` instead. Here is a snippet:

```js
function validate(element) {
  element.value = element.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
}
```

```html
<form action="customer_login.jsp" method="POST">
  Customer Number: <input type="text" name="username" onkeyup="validate(this)" />
  <br />
  Password: <input type="text" name="password" />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `onkeyup` instead of `onkeypress`and remove space from second param of `replace` function

```js
function validate(evt){
    evt.value = evt.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"");  
   }
```

```html
  <form action="login.php" method="POST">
    Customer Number: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" onkeyup="validate(username)" />
    <br />
    Password: <input type="text" name="password" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
  </form>
```