# Laravel - Numbers to input only

Tags: html, laravel, validation, laravel-5

My problem on this code is how to input a numbers only and not any letters

my ***input text***

My problem here is it can accept numbers and not letters but the "E" Letter still persists and can accepts it. how to remove it help please thanks

`{{Form::number('moviePriceToken', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Token Price'])}}`

Comment: Your Laravel validation rules are probably more relevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first off, [e is a number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)). But... you're right, it probably shouldn't be accepted as a number in a form.

Laravel's validator seems to correctly handle it:

```
$validator = Validator::make(['number' => 'e'], [
    'number' => 'required|numeric',
]);

$validator->passes(); // returns false
```

And an `<input type="number">` [correctly rejects it](http://jsfiddle.net/ohd6qgc9/).

[image]

Comment: no sir, i need to constraints when i type it to the form inputs

Comment: so how can i remove that when im typing

Comment: If you're referring to *typing* instead of submitting, see the duplicate question I've linked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966417/prevent-typing-non-numeric-in-input-type-number

Comment: hey sir im not familiar with javascript, jquery or ajax but I have this one line code here and it is perfect for my code ..` <input type="number"  onkeydown="javascript: return event.keyCode == 69 ? false : true" />` how can I implement this code type to my form-collective input number above my code? how can i transform it like that

Comment: Probably something like `{{Form::number('moviePriceToken', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Token Price', 'onkeydown' => 'javascript: return event.keyCode == 69 ? false : true'])}}`.

Comment: okay you earn a badge thanks