# Dynamic input text box id doesnt match the regex format. shows undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, match

I have a dynamic input boxes having the following ids, points0, points1,points2 etc. I want to make sure that these input boxes shoould match only numbers. So I used the following code but in console it always shows

> TypeError: $(...).val(...) is undefined

So I used the following code. I am looping over input text boxes.

```js
var result = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
var points = 'Enter a valid point.';
var regex = '/^[A-Za-z!@#></!?\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g';
 if ($("#points" + j).val().match(regex)) {
                    $('#points' + j + ' + span').html('');
                    $('#points' + j).after('<span class="' + errTextboxClass + '" style="color:#e03b3b;">' + points + '</span>');
                    $('#points' + j).focus();
                }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In my Laravel blade I am looping some answers,

```
 @if($ans)
 @for($j=0;$j<count($ans) ;$j++)
 <input class="form-control " name="points[]" id="points{{$j}}" placeholder="POINTS"  value="<?php echo $ans[$j]['points'];?>">
@endfor
@endif
```

Comment: Please show us the html object with the id `points`, also where did you define `j`

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update with relevant HTML and script

Comment: please see my updated question.

Comment: @Oops I still don't see any html, and by look at your error, it cant find and element with the id `points0`

Comment: It si not a laravel question. Please edit, scroll down and then click edit above snippet and add RENDERED HTML and relevant script (where you define j for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use a better selector for the `input` elements. You can use `input[id^='points']` for example. This will look for `input` elements with a the `id` that starts with `points`.

Consider the following example:

```
var results = $("input[id^='points']");
var points = 'Enter a valid point.';
var regex = '/^[A-Za-z!@#></!?\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g';
results.each(function(i, el) {
  if ($(el).val().match(regex)) {
    console.log("Match on #" + $(el).attr("id"));
    $(el).next('span').html('');
    $("<span>", {
      class: "errTextboxClass"
    }).css("color", "#e03b3b;").html(points).insertAfter($(el));
    $(el).focus();
  }
});
```

Using `.each()` we can iterate each of the matching elements and test them against the RegEx pattern. You might also consider a different pattern. It looks like you want to allow only numbers, could try:

```
^[\D]+$
```

This would match any Non-Digit. If it were me, I would prevent the User from being able to enter non-digits in the field itself using `.keypress()`. For example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("input[id^='points']").keypress(function(e) {
    console.log(e.which);
    if (e.which !== 46 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
label {
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>Points 1</label> <input id="points1" type="text">
</div>
<div>
  <label>Points 2</label> <input id="points2" type="text">
</div>
<div>
  <label>Name</label> <input id="name1" type="text">
</div>
```

See More:

- [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
- [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)
- [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/)
- [Prevent typing non-numeric in input type number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966417/prevent-typing-non-numeric-in-input-type-number)